# Display Wordpress User Role on User Profile

Tags: php, wordpress, roles, profile

I need to insert user roles (multiple per user) onto a profile. So far what I have is:

```
<?php 
    $user_info = get_the_author_meta();
    echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
    echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "\n";
    echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
    echo 'Profile User ID: ' . implode(', ', get_user_meta( $user_id, 'roles' ));
    //echo $authordata;
    //$user = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    echo get_the_author_meta('role');
```

How do I dynamically pull in user roles?

Comment: This might be answered here: [Get Multiple Roles With Get Users](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/get-multiple-roles-with-get-users)

Comment: What do you mean by `How do I dynamically pull in user roles?` ? Dynamically pull where?

Comment: I'm trying to echo the user roles out onto a member profile page.